# Meaning and mathematical origins of "$S$ lies in a small range $\overline{E}\pm \Delta \overline{E}$" as used in statistical physics?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

The fundamental relation of thermodynamics is:
$$
dS=\beta d\overline{E} - pd\overline{V}
$$

It is exact for infinitesimal variations of $\overline{E}$ and $\overline{V}$ and it can be integrated over paths.

In many text of thermodynamics, one finds the following language (for instance page 11 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.2067):

> To build intuition, it is useful to think of the entropy S as roughly
> the logarithm of the [temperature, the pressure and the chemical
> potential] lie in small ranges E ± ∆E, V ± ∆V and N ± ∆N. This is at
> best approximately true, but in ordinary thermodynamics this
> approximation is commonly employed and yields spectacularly good
> results. That is why in thermodynamics people often say the entropy is
> the logarithm of the number of microstates for which the observables
> E, V and N lie within a small range of their specified values.

This type of terminology is also used on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(statistical_thermodynamics)#Counting_of_microstates)

> For a system with some specified energy E, one takes Ω to be the number of energy eigenstates within a macroscopically small energy range between E and E + δE. In the thermodynamical limit, the specific entropy becomes independent on the choice of δE.

I cannot understand where the notion E ± ∆E, V ± ∆V, and N ± ∆N come from? At what point does the terminology of infinitesimals fail to require us to use the terminology "small range" instead?

Answer (score 2):

If uncertainty of energy of a discrete system is too small, the number of compatible microstates $W$ is too small to obtain smooth enough entropy function of that energy via $S=k_B \ln W$. Some range in $E$ is allowed to obtain smoother entropy function so it can be differentiated.

If the system is not discrete, i.e. its states form a continuum, then this is not necessary and one can define entropy for given energy based on $6N-1$ dimensional measure of the energy surface $\Sigma_E$ as $S = k_B \ln \Omega_{\Sigma_E}$. This turns out to have almost the same result (for macroscopic systems) as using $6N$ dimensional measure of the phase space for the phase space shell with energy in range $E,E+\Delta E$. In other words, change of magnitude of $\Delta E$ does not influence properties of $S$ and thus it does not matter.